# What are features which make Oracle and SQL Server database an ORDBMS?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I don't have much idea about ORDBMS features. However, I read somewhere that Oracle and SQL Server are ORDBMS. Can any one guide/tell me to know the exact differences (for Oracle and SQL Server) compare to any other non-ORDBMS (RDBMS) database?

Comment: Thanks Channa.  There will be tons of differences between the two.  I would suggest reading over the documentation for both to compare.  The oracle docs introduce ORD concepts and cover oracle features in-depth.  https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/adobj/index.html

Comment: @Channa https://pediaa.com/what-is-the-difference-between-rdbms-and-ordbms/ The difference between the two is the ability to store object ad object relationships.

Comment: @alexgibbs, thanks for sharing the link. However, i didn't ask for the differences b/w these 2 database. I need to know the features which put these both databases in the category of ORDBMS compare to any other RDBMS like mysql.

Comment: @Channa mySql is not going to give you the same support for object store and object relation mapping

Comment: @Channa It's worth noting that Oracle's Object-Relational features are not required.  You can still use regular relational technologies in Oracle, and in fact I would encourage you to avoid the OR features as that technology was a fad that never made much sense.  Oracle is now a multi-model database - it allows XML, JSON, key-value, document, spatial, graph, OR, and everything else you can think of.  But just because it has those features doesn't mean we have to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDBMS stands for Relational Database Management System and this is the basis for SQL, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, and Microsoft Access.

A Relational database management system (RDBMS) is a database management system (DBMS) that is based on the relational model.

In opposite to that an ORDBMS is an RDBMS that implements object-oriented features such as user-defined types, inheritance, and polymorphism.

Concrete examples might show what it is all about like this [example in Oracle documenation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14260/adobjxmp.htm).